# Array-Properties with the SeralizedPath-Attribute can't be serialized by Serializer

Tags: php, xml, symfony, serialization, normalization

I have the problem that Properties with SerializedPath attributes, which I convert to an XML via Symfony Serializer (SerializerInterface, symfony/serializer-pack), does not have an expected behavior with arrays. Instead, the AbstractObjectNormalizer throws an exception. Symfony and related packages are using v6.2.5.

**My goal** is to create an XML like this one, with e.g. the following Object:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <payment>
        <allowedMethods>
            <include name="Method A"/>
            <include name="Method B"/>
        </allowedMethods>
    </payment>
</response>
```

```php
// This is not working
class Payment
{
    #[SerializedPath('[payment][allowedMethods][include][@name]')]
    public array $methods = ['Method A', 'Method B'];
}

// ...

$this->serializer->serialize(new Payment(), 'xml');
```

**But it results** to the following Exception: `The element you are trying to set is already populated: "[payment][allowedMethods][include][@name]".`
which is thrown in the `AbstractObjectNormalizer` of Symfony:

```php
if (null !== $classMetadata && null !== $serializedPath = ($attributesMetadata[$attribute] ?? null)?->getSerializedPath()) {
    $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    if ($propertyAccessor->isReadable($data, $serializedPath) && null !== $propertyAccessor->getValue($data, $serializedPath)) {
        throw new LogicException(sprintf('The element you are trying to set is already populated: "%s".', (string) $serializedPath));
    }
    $propertyAccessor->setValue($data, $serializedPath, $attributeValue);

    return $data;
}
```

**My expected behavior** would be that it behaves identically to the scalar values and therefore recognizes the @ as an XML attribute and the rest as nodes:

```php
// This is working great!
class Payment
{
    #[SerializedPath('[payment][usedMethod][@name]')]
    public string $usedMethod = 'Method A';
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <payment>
        <usedMethod name="Method A"/>
    </payment>
</response>
```

I've been trying to identify the exact problem and find a solution for some time, but since `SerializedPath` is very new (since Symfony 6.2), there is no great documentation for it. Internally it uses the `PropertyAccessor`, but where I could not find a suitable solution either.

Can someone maybe explain me the problem in more detail or even know a solution? Or even an alternative way. I'm trying to do it via the `SerializedPath` to avoid all the nested DTOs that are just there to map the (not always plausible) data model of the XML.

Another quite interesting fact is, **if you comment out the thrown Exception** in the `AbstractObjectNormalizer` it kind of works (for json fully, for xml partially, because the array can only hold one entry because of the annotation key):

```php
class Payment
{
    #[SerializedPath('[payment][allowedMethods][include]')]
    public array $methods = [
        '@name' => 'Method A'
    ];
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <payment>
        <allowedMethods>
            <include name="Method A"/>
        </allowedMethods>
    </payment>
</response>
```